# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using these packages with no specific versions assigned to them.

```
 firebase_auth: any
 firebase_core: any
 cloud_firestore: any
 tab_indicator_styler: any
 sizer: any
 device_preview: any
 dotted_border: any
```

and I keep getting this message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform firebase-auth-21.0.3.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find firebase-auth-21.0.3.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/21.0.3/firebase-auth-21.0.3.aar
> Failed to transform firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:20.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:20.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth-interop/20.0.0/firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar
> Failed to transform firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:20.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:20.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth-interop/20.0.0/firebase-auth-interop-20.0.0.aar
> Failed to transform play-services-auth-api-phone-17.4.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find play-services-auth-api-phone-17.4.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone/17.4.0/play-services-auth-api-phone-17.4.0.aar
> Failed to transform play-services-safetynet-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find play-services-safetynet-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-safetynet/17.0.0/play-services-safetynet-17.0.0.aar
> Failed to transform browser-1.0.0.aar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find browser-1.0.0.aar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/browser/browser/1.0.0/browser-1.0.0.aar
> Failed to transform legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-core-ui/1.0.0/legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar
> Failed to transform coordinatorlayout-1.0.0.aar (androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not find coordinatorlayout-1.0.0.aar (androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.0.0/coordinatorlayout-1.0.0.aar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I'm not sure but I think this is happening because I didn't put specific versions.
I tried  firebase_auth: ^3.4.1 instead of  firebase_auth: any. But it didn't work.
My flutter version is 3.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66137539/62576 Also, please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of the information already available in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning  to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is meaningless. You should review [ask].

Comment: I tried that already but it didn't work. Also, I know the title was useless:) I was planning to edit it once I solve the problem so other people can find it quickly.

Comment: No, to do it properly you write the title at the time you post the question, so people know what the question is about and those who can answer it can do so. There's no *I'm going to post a bad question, and when I get an answer I'll make it better* herre.

Comment: you're right, you know. my intention wasn't like that btw. the reason why I did that is because I saw tons of questions similar to mine but non of them worked. So I wanted to address the problem in the best way possible after solving it. that's it!

Comment: anyway, you have a valid point here so I edited the title :).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there was a version conflict.
Try the stable version of firebase.
My flutter version is 3.0.4.

```dart
flutter clean
```

```dart
firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
firebase_core: ^1.8.0
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.17
```

```dart
flutter pub get
```

The latest version always introduces problems such as bugs, so it is recommended to immobilize the version.

Comment: it didn't work for me :(